# general useable alias names for tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

if we define tables with columns we have to use company specific naming conventions.

new employees have often problems in understanding all this table and columnnames.

so i had the idea that it would be great if we could define that a table 'Customer' could always be referenced by 'Kunde' and the 
Column 'SPR' referenced by 'spezialPreis'.

And i want to define these alias names in the database schema so that nobody has to know the oldstyled orginal names.

is something like this possible?

special interessted is a solution with ms sql server.

additional Information: the main goal is not to bypass a naming convention. it is to let old application work with old namings and let us make new ones with new and better understanding namings. 
additional we can't use views, because we want to use it in all statements. insert, update, delete, alter, grant,... what ever..

Comment: You could try using views, but you would have to keep them up to date (if you add a column to the table, you have to update the view as well) and you'd lose design-time capabilities like referential integrity.

Comment: So you want to bypass a naming convention? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a computed column:

```
alter table customer add kunde as (old_column_name_here)
```

You cannot readily *remove* the old name, unless you use a view.  But this at least adds the new name, so you can migrate to using it (and, perhaps, eventually rename the old name to `kunde`).

Comment: and do i write any insert/update statement? and what about indexes?